# How to abbreviate any non-html text inside a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create fixed size `div` that limits the shown text by abbreviating anything that overflows the div.

```
<div style="text-overflow:ellipsis; width:100px;height:100px">
<b>my headline</b>
<p></p>
this is some more text
this is some more text
<td> some table elements</td>
this is some more text
this is some more text
this is some more text
this is some more textthis is some more textthis is some more text
</div>
```

But this css approach using `text-overflow:ellipsis` does not work here.
I explicit want to limit anything inside the outer div. Included is not only plain text, but also html markup tags like `<b>, <p>, <i>, <tr>, <td>`.

Could this be corrected? Or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See working sample below:

```html
<div style="text-overflow:ellipsis; width:100px;height:100px;overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap;">
<b>my headline</b>
<p></p>
this is some more text
this is some more text
<td> some table elements</td>
this is some more text
this is some more text
this is some more text
this is some more textthis is some more textthis is some more text
</div>
```

`text-overflow` works only when conditions below are **true**:

1. The element's width is **constrained**.
2. The element have `overflow` value **not** `visible` and `white-space:nowrap` set.

From [MDN Mozzilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow)

> This property only affects content that is overflowing a block container element in its inline progression direction (not text overflowing at the bottom of a box, for example). Text can overflow when it is prevented from wrapping (e.g., due to ‘white-space: nowrap’) or a single word being too long to fit.

This CSS property doesn't force an overflow to occur; to do so and make text-overflow to be applied, the author must apply some additional properties on the element, like setting overflow to hidden.

Your code doesn't suite to condition 2, so i've add `overflow:hidden` and `white-space:nowrap` properties and everything started to work well...

Comment: What if there is an additional inner `div`. Is it also possible to apply the overflow from the outer div down to child divs automatically?

Comment: if you add `display:inline` into inner div it would work

Comment: Hm, I have another problem: the inner text to be rendered is so long that is normally gets automatically broken into several lines. With this ellipsis, the text ends in the first line abbreviated. Is it possible to tell css not to limit this first line? Probably not due to the `no-wrap`?

Comment: My guess is that in case if you have another problem create new question and give me a link to it, i will try to assist you when i have time...

Comment: 1. The element must have a width defined (% and em work for example) 2. Element must have an overflow property other than visible (hidden, scroll, auto). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow

Comment: @steveax Thanks for your correction, i've updated answer !